# Does ArcMap have a Pan To Layer command?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, pan

In an Attribute Table, I am able to choose Pan to Feature (rather than Zoom to Feature) to refocus the map without changing the zoom level. Is there a similar Pan to Layer option (and/or shortcut key) when in the Table of Contents, to match the Zoom to Layer?

(The workaround is, obviously, Zoom to Layer and then reset the scale -- I'm just looking for a simpler way.)

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a button to do this in customize mode, but you could create a Python addin that pans to the centroid of the layer, for instance.

Comment: Another work around is to change your scale settings to only one scale, that way "zoom to layer" would default to your set scale.

Comment: @GISKid -- Interesting idea, can you elaborate on how to do that (presumably as an Answer)?

Comment: @GISKid, while that's a great idea, it doesn't work. Zoom to layer is disabled when fixed scale is set for the data frame.

Comment: Not quite what you asked but if you hold down the Alt key when you click on a layer in the Top it will zoom to full extent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The python addin button is actually simpler than I first thought. Just highlight a layer in the TOC and the button will pan to it.

```py
import arcpy, pythonaddins

class ButtonClass1(object):
    """Implementation for pantolayer_addin.button (Button)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False
    def onClick(self):        
        try:    
            lyr = pythonaddins.GetSelectedTOCLayerOrDataFrame()
            mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("current")
            df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
            df.panToExtent(lyr.getExtent())            
            arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

            del lyr, mxd, df
        except:
            pass
```

If you wanted, you could introduce code to ensure that disables the button when no layer in TOC is selected or does nothing when a data frame is selected.

Comment: I was hoping you (or somebody) could put together a code snippet for this! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 5):

Another potential workaround (at least in 10.2) that doesn't make you mess with scale would be to right click the layer -> selection -> Select All, then right click the layer -> selection -> Pan to Selected Features, and then clear the selection.

Comment: Aha! This works in 10.1 as well.

Comment: Zooming to layer and then changing the scale back seems like a lot less clicks. +1 as this is a pretty neat idea.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for layers that are not selectable, i.e Rasters